# Unexpected behaviour using OR operator in MongoDB linq query

Tags: linq, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query

I'm creating a linq query to search a MongoDB collection.

I have a boolean which should dictate whether date criteria are applied to a query or not.

The query looks something like this:

```
var matches = collection
.AsQueryable<Event>()
.Where(x => ((!applyDateFilter) || (x.CreatedDate >= startDate && x.CreatedDate < endDate)));
```

Please note, the query above is simplified to illustrate the point only.

The problem is, it is ALWAYS applying the date filtering, even when applyDateFilter is `false`, and I really can't see why this would be.

I'm currently on MongoDB v2.0.6 -- I'm just about to try upgrading to a newer version.

Am I missing something here? The [MongoDB linq documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/) includes details of being able to use the OR operator and boolean constants, so I really can't see what's going on here...

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Pardon my last (deleted) comment -- I misread your question.  Looking at https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/MongoDB.Driver/Linq/Translators/MongoQueryTranslator.cs, the `MongoQueryTranslator` is public, so you may be able to use that to analyse the translated query.

Comment: I do not no linq, but to me, if that boolean is not a field of document in the db, it is better to check it in the program and build the query accordingly. I mean do something like: if(applyDateFilter) {build the query that check date} else {build the query that does not check date}.

Comment: @RobLyndon - thanks for your response. luckily I managed to resolve this issue before I got down to analysing the translated query. This would have been my next step.

Comment: @innoSPG - thanks for your response, this is the route I have gone down in the end. It was quite a complex query, so I did it in a way that meant building up the query dynamically to as to prevent lots of repeated code.

Comment: I'm happy to know that my suggestion helped. Good luck @soupy1976.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thus far I haven't managed to find out why this was happening, so I have gone down the route suggested by @innoSPG of applying the criteria and building the query accordingly.

I first attempted to use PredicateBuilder, but I couldn't get this to work with MongoDB.

So in the end I dynamically built up the query by declaring expressions based on my criteria prior to querying the database. Then I apply these expressions in the `where` clause of the linq query. Here's some code:

```
        IEnumerable<Event> matches;
        Expression<Func<Event, bool>> searchQuery;
        Expression<Func<Event, bool>> dateQuery;

        switch (_searchColumn)
        {
            case "username":
                searchQuery = (x) => x.UserFullName.Contains(_searchQuery) || x.UserEmailAddress.Contains(_searchQuery);
                break;
            case "eventtype":
                searchQuery = (x) => x.Type.In(_eventTypes);
                break;
            default:
                searchQuery = (x) => true;
                break;
        }

        if (applyDateFilter)
        {
            var date = Convert.ToDateTime(_datefilter);
            DateTime startDate = date.Date;
            DateTime endDate = date.AddDays(1).Date;

            dateQuery = (x) => (x.Id >= startDate.ToObjectId() && x.Id < endDate.ToObjectId());
        }
        else
        {
            dateQuery = (x) => true;
        }

            matches = collection
                .AsQueryable<Event>()
                .Where(searchQuery)
                .Where(dateQuery)
                .OrderByDescending((x) => x.Id);
```

Not the nicest code in the world, but you get the idea :-)